# the user to choose what operation he want

Tags: c

I want the user to choose what operation he want addition,soustraction,multiplication,division ou reste de la division and give him the result,i did this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main(){
   int x,y,a,s,m,d,r;
   char v[30];
   printf("donner x= ");
   scanf("%d",&x);
   printf("donner y= ");
   scanf("%d",&y);
   printf("Quelle operation tu veux: ");
   scanf("%s",&v);
   if(v=="addition"){
       a=x+y;
       printf("addition= %d",a);
   } else if(v=="soustraction"){
       s=x-y;
       printf("soustraction= %d",s);
   } else if(v=="multiplication"){
       m=x*y;
       printf("multiplication= %d",m);
   } else  if(v=="division"){
       d=x/y;
       printf("division= %d",d);
   } else{
       r=x%y;
       printf("reste= %d",r);
   }
}
```

Comment: "conio.h"? That's a blast from the past.

Comment: You didn't say what the problem actually is. Are you getting some unexpected result, or nothing at all, or some other problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When inputting strings, don't use the `&`.

```
scanf("%s",&v);
```

Should be:

```
scanf("%s", v);
```

---

C does not use `==` to compare strings.
Instead, use `strcmp`:

```
if( strcmp(v,"addition") == 0 ){
```

Comment: i'm a beginner in c language thank you it works